# What is the most widely accepted term for “circumventing support channels or standard operating procedures to gain faster or better service”?

Tags: terminology

Particularly in the case of tech support, what is the most widely accepted "correct" term for the act of artificially escalating a user or customer request, or maybe even circumventing support, service, or request channels and procedures all together? Are there differing terms for this act when requesting help or support versus when placing resource requests?

Aside from most commonly accepted term(s), does ITIL have an official term for this? All my searches for "disintermediation" AND "ITIL" return results dealing with "outsourcing your helpdesk" or something along those lines.

I seem to recall a colloquial term "turboing", but I cannot reach this website from work: http://www.macwhiz.com/articles/art-of-turboing.html if it is up at all anymore.

A very general term seems to be "disintermediation" but that seems to have been adopted by economics and retail sales disciplines.

Answer (score 2):

My wife and I have all the ITIL 2 and 3 manuals.  There is no term that I found.  I think it would depend.  "Gaming the system" maybe. As an example when I worked for IBM I supported the support system RETAIN so would "game the system" by sending my bug reports straight to level 2 and bypass the help desk operators who would usually check the details.
  ITIL would probably differentiate between sidestepping the service desk **function** and the incident or problem management **processes**.  And both would depend on how these were implemented.  As an example for many situations I do not go through the Service Desk but directly manage incidents as part of my role.

Comment: thanks for the researched reply. I feel that I have asked a question that does not have a definitive answer, at least not without some kind of actual survey. However you covered the second part of my question thoroughly. Since you have real-world experience from a major organization: what was the colloquial term or phrase you used when you were speaking with your fellow IBM employees working on RETAIN? E.g., "Alice, I had to game the system today, could you please resolve that ticket by tomorrow?" or "Warning: the new employee Bob is really fond of gaming the system."

Comment: I think it would be very much context and perspective driven.  For example: "old boys network" where people who know each other in a company and respect their view will maybe help each other.  Back-channel is fairly common.  "Leverages contacts" has appeared in my appraisals a few times.  I think that I would only say "game the system" when discussing generalities and would usually use more specific terms like "escalated to level 2 myself".  Sorry to be so vague but as I said I do feel the terms used would depend on context and perspective. One man's initiative is another's "loose cannon"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **jumping the queue** or **jumping the line** which may be US specific